# Making start link for program

Tags: symbolic-link

I'm trying to make a clickable startup link for a new version of Arduino IDE, which is supplied as an AppImage file.
I can start the file by selecting it and pressing return.
I have created a link to the AppImage, which does start the IDE, if it is in the same directory, just by double-clicking on it.
If I move that new link to the desktop, it no longer works by clicking on it, but it still works by right-clicking and selecting "run as program": it starts the IDE as needed.

**I want it to work by clicking on it from the desktop or the dock.**

(As an aside, I have tried to make a .desktop file that would start the AppImage file, without success. I've given up on that approach, after several days spent looking for answers, with all sorts of accepted answers and tens of different ubuntu incantations to make it go, which don't make it go. I'm tempted to revert to Windows, where I can right-click on anything and make a shortcut in 1.5 seconds.)

Comment: Don't know why you want to do this, but the purpose of an app image file is to be portable. You could try converting to a `.deb` file first and installing it, using [this](https://github.com/deepin-espanol/AppImageToDeb) and it should work.

Comment: If the link works as log as it is in the same directory as the IDE, you will probably need to supply a full path to the executable (starting with `/`).

Comment: @Jos It has a full path, and the link works by right-clicking and choosing "run as program", while residing on the desktop, as I mentioned.